# Put the contents of pdf at the center of canvas in Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, apache, pdfbox

I am working with Apache PDFBox 2.0.8. My Objective is to convert a PDF into Image and enlarge the canvas and put the contents in the center so that i can put some header and footer in the remaining space.
My issue is that the canvas is getting enlarged  but the contents are not getting centered, they are stick to the bottom.

```
public class PDFRescale {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
    String pdfFilename = "/MuhimbiPOC/Templates/Source_doc_withheaderfooter.pdf";
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfFilename));
    PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
    PDPage pge = new PDPage();
    PDFRescale ps = new PDFRescale();


    int pageCounter = 0;
    for (PDPage page : document.getPages())
    {
        final PDRectangle mediaBox = pge.getMediaBox();
        mediaBox.setUpperRightX((float) (mediaBox.getUpperRightX()));
        mediaBox.setUpperRightY((float) (mediaBox.getUpperRightY() * 1.5));
        mediaBox.setLowerLeftY((float) (mediaBox.getLowerLeftY() * 1.5));

        // note that the page number parameter is zero based
        page.setMediaBox(mediaBox);
        BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageCounter, 140, ImageType.RGB);

        // suffix in filename will be used as the file format

            ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, pdfFilename + "-" + (pageCounter++) + ".png", 140);

    }
    System.out.println("Task Completed ... ");
    document.close();

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to re scale PDF without converting it to image. ?

Answer (score 1):

> My issue is that the canvas is getting enlarged but the contents are not getting centered, they are stick to the bottom.

That is your issue for PDF pages whose `mediaBox.getLowerLeftY()` is `0`. While this is very common, it is not required. If you had worked with a more generic selection of PDFs, you'd have seen that *your issue is that the former contents eventually can be anywhere, even off-screen!*

The cause is that you do

```
mediaBox.setUpperRightY((float) (mediaBox.getUpperRightY() * 1.5));
mediaBox.setLowerLeftY((float) (mediaBox.getLowerLeftY() * 1.5));
```

This would only work if the origin was somewhere on the horizontal mid-screen axis.

Instead use something like

```
mediaBox.setUpperRightY(mediaBox.getUpperRightY() + mediaBox.getHeight() * 0.5f);
mediaBox.setLowerLeftY(mediaBox.getLowerLeftY() - mediaBox.getHeight() * 0.5f);
```

Another issue of your code: you only set the **MediaBox** and ignore the **CropBox**. `pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI` on the other hand uses the **CropBox**. Only for PDF pages without explicit **CropBox** your code enlarges the page area. For a generic solution you should also adapt the **CropBox**.

Comment: Is there any way to re scale PDF without converting it to image. ?

Comment: @PrashantChaudhary *"Is there any way to re scale PDF without converting it to image?"* - Yes: You can insert a scaling instruction at the beginning of the content stream (array) of each page. Beware: This only changes the page contents, not annotations. If your PDFs also have annotations (like AcroForm form fields), you have to scale their **Rect** entries, too.